# Coroutine being skipped when running background thread

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

So I am encountering a weird issue in my code where a coroutine is being completely skipped when I debug through my code and I am not sure why it is happening.

Basically I call this method(insertLabelBind) in my Fragment in the onViewCreated.

```
//FRAGMENT
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val addLabelButton: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_edit_add_label_row_button)
        val addQuestionButton: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_edit_add_question_response_button)
        val editBookImage: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_image_edit)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        bindBasicInfo(view)
        bindLabels(view)
        bindQandA(view)
        addLabelButton.setOnClickListener{
                insertLabelBind(view)

            //add to label live data

        }}

     private fun insertLabelBind(view: View) = launch{
        val word: EditText? = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_label_edit_add_row)
        val labelTag = viewModel.createLabel(word?.text.toString())
        labelTag?.observeOnce(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { tag ->
            if (tag == null) return@Observer
            CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
                setLabelTextInUI(tag, word)
            }
        })
    }
```

Then in the Fragment's ViewModel this gets called and it keeps failing to retrieve for the label result

```
//VIEWMODEL
suspend fun createLabel(label: String): LiveData<LabelTag>? {
            var labelResult: LiveData<LabelTag>? = null
            var userLabelResult: LiveData<UserLabel>? = null

            val labelTag = LabelTag(
                0,
                profileId,
                label,
                LocalDateTime.now().toString(),
                LocalDateTime.now().toString(),
                ""
            )

            labelResult = coverRepository.createLabelTag(labelTag)
            userLabelResult = coverRepository.getSingleUserLabel(profileId, labelResult?.value!!.id)

            if (userLabelResult == null) {
                val userLabel = UserLabel(
                    0,
                    profileId,
                    labelResult!!.value!!.id,
                    1,
                    label,
                    LocalDateTime.now().toString(),
                    LocalDateTime.now().toString(),
                    ""
                )
                userLabelResult = coverRepository.createUserLabel(userLabel)
            }
        return if (userLabelResult != null) {
            labelResult
        } else
            null
    }
```

In the repository, this createLabelTag Method gets called

```
//REPOSITORY
    override suspend fun createLabelTag(labelTag: LabelTag): LiveData<LabelTag>? {
        return withContext(IO) {
            val result = createLabelTagSource(labelTag)
            when (result.status) {
                Status.SUCCESS -> labelTagDao.getTagById(labelTag.id)
                Status.LOADING -> null
                Status.ERROR -> null
            }
        }

    }

    private suspend fun createLabelTagSource(labelTag: LabelTag): Resource<LabelTag> {
        return labelTagDataSource.createLabelTag(
            labelTag
        )
    }
```

This then calls the labelTagDataSource

```
//DATASOURCE
    override suspend fun createLabelTag(labelTag: LabelTag): Resource<LabelTag> {
        return try {
            val fetchedLabelTag = responseHandler.handleSuccess(coverApiService
                .createLabelTag(labelTag))
            val list = listOf(fetchedLabelTag.data!!)
            list.first().profileId = labelTag.profileId
            _downloadedLabelTag.postValue(list)
            fetchedLabelTag
        } catch (e: NoConnectivityException) {
            Log.e("Connectivity", "No internet connection.", e)
            responseHandler.handleException(e)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            responseHandler.handleException(e)
        }
    }
```

The datasource triggers an observer in the repository for the downloadLabelTag and the data gets persisted into the labelTag room DB

```
//REPOSITORY
     labelTagDataSource.apply {
            downloadedLabelTag.observeForever { newLabelTag ->
                persistFetchedLabelTag(newLabelTag)
            }
        }

    private fun persistFetchedLabelTag(labelTags: List<LabelTag>) {
        job = Job()
        job?.let { repoJob ->
            CoroutineScope(IO + repoJob).launch {
                if(labelTags.size > 1)
                    labelTagDao.deleteAll()
                for(result in labelTags){
                    labelTagDao.upsertTag(result)
                }
                repoJob.complete()
            }
        }
    }
```

```
//DAO
interface LabelTagDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun upsertTag(label: LabelTag)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM label_tag WHERE label = :tag")
    fun getLabelByTag(tag: String): LiveData<LabelTag>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM label_tag WHERE id = :id")
    fun getTagById(id: Long): LiveData<LabelTag>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM label_tag WHERE profileId = :profileId")
    fun getTagMultipleTags(profileId: Int): LiveData<List<LabelTag>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM label_tag")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

The issue is occurring the Repository.persistFetchedLabelTag and that CoroutineScope is being completely skipped. This results the ViewModel's labelResult to return null. Would like to know why this coroutine is being skipped. Any help will be grateful.

Comment: Pretty sure it is a bug in the debugger. Still present to this day,